# Can't run sample express app in node container on Windows

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm watching a Docker course from *Pluralsight* and I need to run a Docker source on a Docker container I just downloaded.

Even though I have `package.json` file in the current path, it is not recognized.

```
Usuario@RE MINGW64 /d/node/ExpressSite
$ docker run -p 8080:3000 -v /$(pwd):/var/www -w "/var/www" node:4.4.5 npm start
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@2.15.5
npm info using node@v4.4.5
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.12-boot2docker
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.4.5
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.5
npm ERR! path /var/www/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/www/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/npm-debug.log
```

Why the Pluralsight does the same and it works? What's wrong with my version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official docs https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/:

> If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Engine daemon has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows) directory. So, you can mount files or directories on OS X using.
>
> `docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...`
>
> On Windows, mount directories using:
>
> `docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path> ...`

So, you can create a directory inside `C:\Users\<your_username>` (`code` for example) with your code and mount it inside the container like so:

`docker run -p 8080:3000 -v /c/Users/<your_username>/code:/var/www -w "/var/www" node:4.4.5 npm start`

Please note that your code will be available inside the container in `/var/www/` directory

`pwd` returns `/c/Users/<my_username>`. Try it yourself in Docker terminal.

---

You can use `pwd` for convenience sake:

`docker run -p 8080:3000 -v $(pwd)/code:/var/www -w "/var/www" node:4.4.5 npm start`

Good luck with the course and Dockerize all the things!